# Why am I not able to generate report when I am trying to generate report via a batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file, jasper-reports

I am facing a very strange issue. When I am calling .jrxml file from my java class everything is working fine. But when I am calling the same java class from a batch file I am not able to generate the report. Console is showing some error like this.  Please help me out with this.

The Stacktrace:

```
2012-12-21 16:15:13,466 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport : prepare - Fill 31497899: exception java.lang.NullPointerException 
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluateImage(JRFillImage.java:1034??)  
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillImage.evaluate(JRFillImage.java:1004)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementCo??ntainer.java:258)
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillPageHeader(JRVerticalFille??r.java:403) 
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFill??er.java:264) 
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.ja??va:128)  
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:499) 
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillBandNoOverflow(JRVerticalF??iller.java:439) 
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:946) 
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845) 
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillSubreport.fillSubreport(JRFillSubreport.j??ava:609) 
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRSubreportRunnable.run(JRSubreportRunnable.jav??a:59) 
  at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRThreadSubreportRunner.run(JRThreadSubreportRu??nner.java:205) 
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
```

Comment: Can add a text version of the stacktrace into your question please?

Comment: Can you post the batch file contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it cannot find the image. Try putting the absolute path to the image file, just to debug and see what happens. My guess is that it is looking for the image in the wrong place when you run it from command line.

Comment: Hi, I am given absolute path. While filling the Sub reports also it's giving same error. Please help me to out with this.

Comment: I need to see some code for that, but what I generally do is I put the images and sub reports on the classpath, and I take them as: AccountUser.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("imgName.jpg");, I have an example project you can check out: http://code.google.com/p/jasper-reports-poc/

Comment: yeah, i added all the jars in the class path. Now i am able get the Reports. Thank You!!!

Comment: @Raghupathiraja what JAR's were you missing that caused this exception?

Comment: @Raghupathiraja consider posting your own solution as an answer, and accepting that, as this answer (`try putting absolute path to image file`) wasn't the solution. The solution was `added all jars in class path`